# C Programming - Design

Tags: c

**I'm writing a program that when you subtract 3 from char 'a' you get the answer of char 'x'**

What's the most practical way of doing this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   char letter = 'a'
   int subtract_from_letter = 3;

   /*Not sure what to do here...

    char letter should now equal 'x'. If char letter was equal to 'd', it      
    would now equal 'a'.        

   */

   return 0; 
}
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You could take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to have a global idea of how this site works, and read the [advice on how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) in the help center to see what questions are welcomed here and which are not.

Comment: i.e. What have you tried? Where did you fail? What's the real problem?

Comment: I'm just going through a book of C exercises by myself, trying to learn. This was one of the problems, just little brain teasers.

Comment: Not clear. Could you explain better?

Comment: I changed the wording of the question, I apologise. If char letter was 'd', it would now equal 'a', because d - 3 is 3 letters back.

Comment: It's unclear what you want, give more examples (b,c,d,e,...x,y,z).

Comment: Search for "caesar cipher" and you'll find plenty of solutions.

Comment: z - 2 = x. z - 3 = w.

Comment: Check this answer (use `shift = -3`): http://stackoverflow.com/a/16374718/646887

Comment: "The most practical way" seems to solicit opinions. If you have working code, submit it to [codereview.se]. If you have non-working code, show it. If you have no code and no idea, try something.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do

- convert from the letter to a respective number from 0..25,
- add/subtract
- do a modulo 26 operation
- convert back to a letter.

So the result is

```
int letter_num = letter - 'a';
int result = (letter_num + 26 - subtract_from_letter) % 26; // ensures we stay positive
chat result_letter = result + 'a';
```

For example, with `'a'` and 3, you'll get

```
letter_num = 0
result = 23
result_letter = 'x'
```

`'d'`, however, will give you

```
letter_num = 3
result = (29 - 3) % 26 = 0
result_letter = 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think , youre trying to go for a *circular* print for small *case* alphabets, right?

Try this logic:

1. check if the `letter` is less than `d` (decimal 100) or not before subtraction.
2. If yes, do `(letter + 26 - subtract_from_letter)`
3. otherwise, do `(letter - subtract_from_letter)`
4. print the result using `%c`.

Comment: Surely (`letter + 26 - subtract_from_letter)`?

Comment: @WeatherVane is `(letter+122-subtract_from_letter)`

Comment: @LPs no! Start from `letter = 'c'`, so `letter = 99` then `99+26-3 = 122` which is `'z'`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I misunderstood your comment, you right, but @Sourav Ghosh wrote `(letter + 'z' - subtract_from_letter)` that is `(letter+122-subtract_from_letter)` or I'm missing something?

Comment: @LPs I could have edited the incorrect answer but to be polite I queried it instead.

Comment: @WeatherVane I really appriciate your patience.  However, this kind of error is commonly due to silly mistakes anf you are always welcome to make the change in the answer body itself. No worries

Answer (score 0):

`a` according to ASCII table is `97 dec` , so when you write :

```
char letter = 'a';
int subtract_from_letter = 3;
int result = letter - subtract_from_letter; // 97 - 3 = 94
```

`94` in decimal, from ASCII table, is ^ in character.

`x` in decimal is 120, so if you want to get `x` from this calculation, you should do this:

```
char letter = 'a';
int subtract_from_letter = 3;
int result = letter - subtract_from_letter + 26; // 97 - 3 + 26 = 120
```

but, it's weird !

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (but safe) way is:

```
   char letter = 'a';
   int substract_from_letter = 3;

   letter = 'a' + ((letter + 'z' - 'a' + 1 - substract_from_letter - 'a') 
                   % ('z' - 'a' + 1));
```