# CS50 Pset 2- ceasar cipher

Tags: c, cs50, caesar-cipher

It isn't showing what I want it to show that is the ciphered version of the input text but instead symbols, as I guess, looks kinda like a '?' comes out as the output in the terminal. could anyone help me in finding what I missed or did wrong?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        string ptext = get_string("plaintext: ");
        int key = (int) argv[1];
        printf("ciphertext: ");
        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(ptext); i < n; i++)
        {
            printf("%c", (( ptext[i] + key ) % 26);
        } 
        printf("\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid input. \n");
    }

}
```

I expect the output of 'hello' to be 'ifmmp' but instead, it doesn't.

Comment: All chars with ASCII values 0..25 are unprintable control characters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is wrong:

```
int key = (int) argv[1];
```

`argv` is an array of `string`, which in CS50 is nothing more than an obfuscated `char *` pointer.

Per [**5.1.2.2.1 Program startup** of the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1):

> The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:
>
> ```
>     int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>
> ```
>     int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent; ...

So `argv[1]` is a `char *` pointer value, which you then assign to an `int` value.  That's taking the address of some memory (say the value in `argv[1]` is `0xFF0403220020480C`) and trying to stuff it into the likely 4 bytes of the `int` variable `key` (which in this case would be assigned the truncated value `0x0020480C`.)

That's not what you appear to be trying to do.

(IMO, your problem here is a perfect example of why CS50's obfuscation of `char *` with the `string` type is a tremendously bad idea.  You simply can't understand C without understanding pointers and `NUL`-terminated `char` strings accessed via a `char *` pointer, and the obfuscation that `string` does makes that harder.)

If you want to [convert a string to a numeric value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021725/how-to-convert-a-string-to-integer-in-c), you likely want [something like `strtol()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.1.4)  ([never use `atoi()` as it has no error checking and its use can invoke undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710018/why-shouldnt-i-use-atoi)):

```
char firstCharNotConverted;

// set errno to zero as strtol()
errno = 0;
long key = strtol( argv[ 1 ], &firstCharNotConverted, 0 );

// if errno is now non-zero, the call to strtol() failed (per Linux man page)
// need to examine key and the contents of firstCharNotConverted
// to figure out why
if ( errno != 0 )
{
    ...
}
```

Proper headers omitted as an exercise for anyone trying to use this code  ;-)

Note that I used `long` for `key`, as you can't do complete and proper error checking on `strtol()` if you cast the return value to `int`.

Error checking `strtol()` can be somewhat complex as the value returned (and assigned to `key` in the above code) can be any value and there are no values possible that aren't legitimate `long` values that `strtol()` can return to indicate an error, so for proper error checking you need to check the values of both `errno` and `firstCharNotConverted` to properly determine if an error did occur. The [Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) states:

> Since strtol() can legitimately return 0, LONG_MAX, or LONG_MIN
>          (LLONG_MAX or LLONG_MIN for strtoll()) on both success and failure,
>          the calling program should set errno to 0 before the call, and then
>          determine if an error occurred by checking whether errno has a
>          nonzero value after the call.

After that call to `strtol()`, you need to check if `key` is `LONG_MIN`, or `LONG_MAX` with `errno` equal to `ERANGE` for underflow or overflow, or if `key` is `0` you need to check the contents of `firstCharNotConverted` to determine why the conversion may have failed.  Note that if `key` is zero and `firstCharNotConverted` isn't equal to `argv[ 1 ]`, then input string was properly converted from zero.

Your Ceaser cipher implementation is also wrong:

```
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(ptext); i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", (( ptext[i] + key ) % 26);
    } 
    printf("\n");
```

will just print out characters with values from `0` through `25` - which aren't letters in the ASCII character set.

There a numerous Ceaser ciphers questions already posted here, so I'm not going to write the code.  See [Caesar's Cipher Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464936/caesars-cipher-code) for one example question.

Comment: `printf("%c", (( ptext[i] + key ) % 26);` is wrong too, should be ``printf("%c", (( ptext[i] + key ) % 26 + 'A');``, but this will only deal with all capital text

Comment: @Jabberwocky  True.  I didn't reach that far yet.  But that's a simple error and doesn't seem like the root cause is a misunderstanding about how pointers, strings, and conversion to `int` values works.  And there are probably dozens of Ceaser cipher questions that would provide and answer to that problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here `printf("%c", (( ptext[i] + key ) % 26);`. Specifically with `% 26`. It certainly looks exactly like the problem set:

> More formally, if p is some plaintext (i.e., an unencrypted message),
>   pi is the ith character in p, and k is a secret key (i.e., a
>   non-negative integer), then each letter, ci, in the ciphertext, c, is
>   computed as
>
> ci = (pi + k) % 26
>
> wherein % 26 here means “remainder when dividing by 26.”

But, the pset goes on to say:

> think of A (or a) as 0, B (or b) as 1, …, H (or h) as 7, I (or i) as
>   8, …, and Z (or z) as 25.

The problem is that the character `ptext[i]` is the [*ascii* value of the letter](http://www.asciitable.com/), not the "alphabet index".

Perhaps review the spoiler in the pseudocode section of the Lab, particularly #5:

> Iterate over each character of the plaintext:
>
> - If it is an uppercase letter, rotate it, preserving case, then print out the rotated character
> - If it is a lowercase letter, rotate it, preserving case, then print out the rotated character
> - If it is neither, print out the character as is

You may find this [walkthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ergRKv3DglI) (from an earlier iteration of the course) helpful.